# Making squares on bootstrap

Tags: bootstrapping

[this is a psd file and i want to make the squares with bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIYzQ.png)

I would like to make this squares and I cant have any solutions.
i tried with this!i make a sample but i cant make it works perfect..i have some realy big issues and i am a newbie..can someone help me with at least one square??
i tried with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIYzQ.png). I've made a sample but I can't make it works perfectly. I've some really big issues,can someone help me with at least one square?

```
<style type="text/css">
    div[class*="col-"] > .square-responsive,
    span[class*="col-"] > .square-responsive,
    ol[class*="col-"] > .square-responsive,
    ul[class*="col-"] > .square-responsive,
    li[class*="col-"] > .square-responsive{
        padding-bottom:0.5cm;
        padding-left:0.5cm;
        padding-right:0.3cm;
        padding-top:0.4cm;
        height:7.51;
        width:3cm;
        line-height:0.8cm;

    }
    div[class*="col-"] > .rect-responsive,
    span[class*="col-"] > .rect-responsive,
    ol[class*="col-"] > .rect-responsive,
    ul[class*="col-"] > .rect-responsive,
    li[class*="col-"] > .rect-responsive{
        padding-bottom:0.5cm;
        padding-left:0.5cm;
        padding-right:0.3cm;
        padding-top:0.4cm;
        height:7.51cm;
        width:3cm;
        line-height:0.8cm;
    }
    .square-responsive,
    .rect-responsive{
         position:relative; 
         overflow:hidden;
         background-color: #202f3f;
    }
    .square-responsive > *,
    .rect-responsive > *{
        position:absolute; 
    }
    .square-responsive > .content,
    .rect-responsive > .content {

    }
</style>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="square-responsive">
              <div class="content">
              <div class="color=white">
                   Boat Name
                   </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="square-responsive">
              <div class="content">

</div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please give me some help.